# Forwarding request to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I am trying to forward a request to tomcat from nginx.

I can reach it from the outside using scoring.megahooked.com:8080/Bowling but I can't seem to get "scoring.megahooked.com". Can someone point me in the right direction?

scoring.conf includes this.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     scoring.megahooked.com;


    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7070/Bowling;
                                                    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo, you've put `127.0.0.1:7070` instead of `:8080`

Comment: Would have been if tomcat had not been at 7070 behind the firewall